# Power BI - Create a column to show the data against one item

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with repeating values in a single column, I am trying to filter the data corresponding to just one value. I have tried Pivoting the table and it didn't help, it would be helpful to get the solution using DAX or Power Query.

| S.No. | Make | Sale Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mercedes | 01.08.2020 |
| 2 | BMW | 02.08.2020 |
| 3 | Hyundai | 03.09.2020 |
| 4 | Honda | 04.06.2020 |
| 5 | BMW | 16.03.2020 |
| 6 | BMW | 06.08.2020 |
| 7 | Mercedes | 01.02.2021 |
| 8 | Honda | 18.08.2020 |
| 9 | BMW | 12.04.2020 |
| 10 | Honda | 10.03.2021 |

I need each Make to display their own Sale Date's in their own column similar to the table below

| BMW |
| --- |
| 02.08.2020 |
| 16.03.2020 |
| 06.08.2020 |
| 12.04.2020 |

Comment: Use Pivot or the matrix visual

Comment: But I need this view for every Vehicle Make

Answer (score 1):

Using your example data:

[image: Example Dataset]

In the data editor, select the Make and Sale Date and Pivot the items

[image: Pivot Layout]

Ensure that the 'Values Column' is 'Sale Date' and that the aggregate value is set to 'Don't Aggregate'

[image]

Which will give you a table with each make in its own column, and the dates of the sale

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your reply but in my case it is throwing me an error saying “Cannot apply a pivot operation over a table that contains columns with nested data”.
Is there any Power Query or DAX formula that can help me for the same.